# JQuery image slider with arrows

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've built a basic image slider using HTML, CSS, and JS (Jquery). There are 5 images in total and users can switch between them using arrows, everything works fine so far but I want the right arrow to disappear if it reaches the last image and that's where I get stuck. The problem is that the right arrow disappears right after I reach the second image. Any idea on how to fix that? Thanks in advance!

IMG of the slider
[image]

IMG of my problem (the right arrow disappears immediately when I reach the second image, that's supposed to happen only with the last image.)
[image]

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').on('click',function(event) {
        var images = $('.slider-inner').find('img');
        var currentImg = $('.active')
        var nextImg = currentImg.next();
        var lastImg = images.last();
        var rightArrow = $('.next');

        images.not(':first').hide();

        if (nextImg.length) {
            currentImg.removeClass('active');
            nextImg.addClass('active');
            nextImg.fadeIn();
        }
        
        if (lastImg.length) {
            rightArrow.hide();
        }
       
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.prev').on('click',function() {
        var currentImg = $('.active')
        var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

        if (prevImg.length) {
            currentImg.removeClass('active');
            prevImg.addClass('active');
        }
        

        
    });
});
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    color: white;
    
}

.container {
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.slider-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    max-height: 675px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.1875em;
    border: black solid 7px;
}

.slider-inner img {
    display: none;
    
}

.slider-inner img.active {
    display: inline-block;
}

.prev, .next {
    margin-top: 18.75em;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.prev {
    z-index: 100;
    margin-right: -2.8125em;
    position: relative;
    
}


.next {
    margin-left: -2.8125em;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}



.nadpis {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.podnadpis {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.img-slider {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vlastna responzivna stranka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="nadpis">Take zaujimave veci, ktore sa daju spravit s JS a JQuery</h1>
        <h2 class="podnadpis">Image Slider</h2>
        <div class="slider-outer">
            <img src="img-slider/arrow-left.png" alt="left arrow" class="prev">
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <img src="img-slider/john-jpg.jpg" class="active" alt="A game character witha quote saying Dont you kids watch horror movies?, you never, ever, split up.">
                <img src="img-slider/butterflies-jpg.jpg" alt="A game character looking at an enthogy">
                <img src="img-slider/andrew-jpg.jpg" alt="Three characters, one from the future, one from the present and one from the past">
                <img src="img-slider/taylor-jpg.jpg" alt="Three characters, one from the future, one from the present and one from the past"">
                <img src="img-slider/vince-.jpg.jpg" alt="A bar with a guy sitting there">
                <img src="img-slider/conrad.jpg" alt="Conrad">
            </div>
            <img src="img-slider/arrow-right.png" alt="next arrow" class="next">
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This reproduces your code - https://ibb.co/WzCv1tT. Please edit your code so that the snippet can reproduce the slider, and I will help you.

Comment: I've tried editing it, how does it look now? Thanks for notifying me about this. Looks still the same to me, I'll make a codepen snippet.

Comment: nevermind, it shows the same everywhere.. try adding the code into your code editor and see if that does anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (lastImg.hasClass("active")) {
         rightArrow.hide();
}
```